# Why were people raised as food in Gundam: G Reconguista?

Tags: gundam

I'm catching up on Gundam: G Reconguista and they keep talking about Kuntala.  The brief discriptions so far were that they are lower class citizens and that they used to be raised as food.

Cannibalism? For serious?  Humans would make the worst stock.  You'd have to wait 16 years to get a decent amount of anything to eat.  Cows mature in less than 5 (2ish maybe?), and sheep and goats are fast to raise.  And they eat grass, which is usually everywhere.

I found a blurb on a [Gundam wiki](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Kuntala#cite_ref-1), and a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Gundam/comments/2lxba9/several_questions_about_kuntala_in_greco/) asking similar questions, but not much for answers.

- Why were people being raised as food?
- If such a people were freed from bondage, how and why are they still second class citizens and discriminated against?

Comment: 1. plot device, 2. human nature, src: history, ie: minorities, caste system, aristocracy, etc...

Comment: i haven't seen the series but if it's similar to [Soylent Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_Green) then the people being raised just need not know and then they can an "accident" when it's time to harvest when they are older

Comment: I'm under the impression that the people were explicitly raised to be eaten, and therefore didn't know they were going to be eaten because they were ignorant.  However, the general populace knew of what was going on.

Comment: "*And they eat grass, which is usually everywhere.*" well, according to [Wikia on Regild Century](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Regild_Century), "*the surviving people of Earth clustered around an area in the Amazon (the last green place on the planet at the time)*", so it will be difficult to raise enough livestocks to feed existing people? Also, [Kuntala](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Kuntala) themselves are used as "substitute food" in case of food crisis.